# how to put botton right beside the tabel the row data html bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

i want to make a button beside the table data in every row data of table. i've tried to make a new column for it to put the button but there is a border on it. i want it without a border, just the button. i use bootstrap 4 for this

this is my html

```html
<div class="card-body col-10">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Password</th>
                  <th>Phone</th>
                  <th>Privilege</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Password</th>
                  <th>Phone</th>
                  <th>Privilege</th>
              </tfoot>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>System@you.com</td>
                  <td>Edinburgh</td>
                  <td>081290188409</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>System@you.com</td>
                  <td>Edinburgh</td>
                  <td>081290188409</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>System@you.com</td>
                  <td>Edinburgh</td>
                  <td>081290188409</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                  <td>System@you.com</td>
                  <td>Edinburgh</td>
                  <td>081290188409</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                </tr>
               
                                 
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
```

i want to make the button on the right of table beside privilege the button is not a table.

i've tried to make it a table like in this code

```
<div class="card-body col-1">
      <div class="tablen float-left">
        <table class="table table-borderless" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger fas fa-table float-left"></button></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

but it too far from table beside it. i want it just right beside the table.
please help if you know. thank you

Answer (score 1):

With JQuery you can use this ,

It could be solved by CSS3 using :before too but I don't know the exact syntax for it.

so here the JQuery code

```
$("td").each(function (){
    $(this).append("<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger fas fa-table float-left'></button>" );
});
```